# Qual é a maneira correta de utilizar o operador "%" no Sass?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Estou fazendo alterações em uma página que foi feita utilizando Sass, e ainda sou bem iniciante com o framework, e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
%cf {
    &:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Eu entendo que esse código foi feito para que pudesse utilizar mais pra frente em outros lugares, para que não tivesse a necessidade de ficar repetindo o código, mas minha dúvida é: **como eu invoco esse `%cf` para aproveitá-lo em outras partes do meu projeto?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%` é feito para criar um "placeholder" de CSS, e para utiliza-lo vc precisa fazer um `@extend`. Veja a documentação oficial do `placeholder` https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors

Aqui tem um exemplo de como o seu código ficaria

```
%cf {
    &:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.box {
    @extend %cf;
    width:100px;
    background: red;
    etc...
}
```

O `%cf` vai criar um *pseudo elemento* de CSS no elemento com classe `.box` e fazer um `clearfix`

Output do código

```
.box:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Ótima explicação Hugo, entendi perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: @MateusD. fico feliz em ter ajudado, que bom que ficou claro o funcionamento :), ele é muito útil para tratar o :hover tb, não deixe de ver a documentação